# Get the rank of an entry in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get the rank of an activerecord object based on the number of votes its currently received. In my object model, I have a method 'rank' defined as:

```
Object.count(:conditions => ['votes > (?)', self.votes], :distinct => true) + 1
```

That returns the rank. However, elsewhere in my program I have found that I actually need to get this in the mysql query itself. I wanted to try to do something like below:

```
Object.select('id, votes, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "objects"."id") 
FROM "objects" 
WHERE "objects"."votes" > votes) AS rank').limit(10)
```

However, I dont know how to do the 'objects.votes > votes' part. I need to replace '> votes', with some reference to itself. Not sure if that's clear. Any ideas?

Comment: Would it help to provide a SQL solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I will guess that you mean, how do you pass `self.votes` from rails to the SQL query?

You can do this:

```
Object.where("votes > ?",self.votes)
```

So to pass `self.votes` to your query:

```
Object.select('id, votes, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "objects"."id") 
FROM "objects" 
WHERE "objects"."votes" > ?) AS rank',self.votes).limit(10)
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it well enough. I'm doing this in a controller, so there is no self. I'm probably approaching this incorrectly.

Comment: You need something to compare the Object's votes against.  So If you have a Model Post,  and it has many votes,  you'd need to record in the Post the Vote that has the most votes,  then when new votes come in,   you could compare the count of the new vote against the Post's record of the most popular vote, and then determine the rank.